# Azure Cognitive Search:

Tags: python, azure

I have recently upgraded my Azure Cognitive Search instance so it has semantic search.

However, when I add query_type=semantic, in the client search I get the following stacktrace...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call_semantic_search.py", line 34, in <module>
    c, r = main(search_text='what is a ')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "call_semantic_search.py", line 28, in main
    count: float = search_results.get_count()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/search/documents/_paging.py", line 82, in get_count
    return self._first_iterator_instance().get_count()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/search/documents/_paging.py", line 91, in wrapper
    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/search/documents/_paging.py", line 115, in _get_next_cb
    return self._client.documents.search_post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/search/documents/_generated/operations/_documents_operations.py", line 312, in search_post
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: () The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Requested value 'semantic' was not found.
Code: 
Message: The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Requested value 'semantic' was not found.
```

This is the code that I have been using to call the search index.

```py
import logging
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple

import settings as settings
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from search import SearchableItem

TOP = 10
SKIP = 0


def main(search_text: str) -> Tuple[float, Iterable[Dict]]:
    client = SearchClient(
        api_version="2021-04-30-Preview",
        endpoint=settings.SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT,
        index_name=settings.SOCIAL_IDX_NAME,
        credential=AzureKeyCredential(key=settings.SEARCH_SERVICE_KEY)
    )
    logging.info(f"Calling: /search?top={TOP}&skip={SKIP}&q={search_text}")
    search_results = client.search(
        search_text=search_text,
        top=TOP,
        skip=SKIP,
        query_type="semantic",
        include_total_count=True,
    )
    count: float = search_results.get_count()
    results = SearchableItem.from_result_as_dict(search_results)
    return count, results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    count, results = main(search_text='what is a ')
    print(count, list(results))
```

And here is my Azure configuration (I'm able to perform Semantic searches via the portal:

[image]

### EDITS

Taking @Thiago Custodio's advice;

I enabled logging with:

```py
import sys


logger = logging.getLogger('azure')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Configure a console output
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# ...
    search_results = client.search(
        search_text=search_text,
        top=TOP,
        skip=SKIP,
        query_type="semantic",
        include_total_count=True,
        logging_enable=True
    )
# ...
```

And I got the following:

```
DEBUG:azure.core.pipeline.policies._universal:Request URL: 'https://search.windows.net//indexes('idx-name')/docs/search.post.search?api-version=2020-06-30'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata.metadata=none'
    'Content-Length': '86'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': 'fbaafc9e-qwww-11ed-9117-a69cwa6c72e'
    'api-key': '***'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-search-documents/11.3.0 Python/3.11.1 (macOS-13.0-x86_64-i386-64bit)'
```

So this shows the request URL going out is pinned to `api-version=2020-06-30` - in the Azure Portal, if I change the search version to the same, semantic search is unavailable.

I seem to have an outdated version of the search library even though I installed via:

```
pip install azure-search-documents
```

The most notable difference is that in my local `azure/search/documents/_generated/operations/_documents_operations.py` - the `api_version` seems to be hardcoded to `2020-06-30` see:

[image]

Looking at the source, I actually need the `api_version` to be dynamically set, so at the caller I can pass it in the search client. This is something thats already implemented within there main branch of the source, see: [Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/search/azure-search-documents/azure/search/documents/_generated/operations/_documents_operations.py#L739), but for some reason, *my local version is different*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
azure-search-documents==11.4.0b3
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code:

```
search_results = client.search(
        search_text=search_text,
        top=TOP,
        skip=SKIP,
        query_type="semantic",
        include_total_count=True,
    )
```

Semantic search is not a parameter, but an endpoint. Rather than calling `/search`, you should call `/semantic`

that's what you need:

```
def semantic_ranking():
    # [START semantic_ranking]
    from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
    from azure.search.documents import SearchClient

    endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT")
    index_name = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME")
    api_key = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY")

    credential = AzureKeyCredential(api_key)
    client = SearchClient(endpoint=endpoint,
                          index_name=index_name,
                          credential=credential)
    results = list(client.search(search_text="luxury", query_type="semantic", query_language="en-us"))
```

note: query_type part in the last line

Comment: Are you able to post the Python? I have been following this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/search/azure-search-documents/samples/sample_semantic_search.py#L56

Comment: Based on your edits, I feel like my code and your code are the same.

Comment: It's possible you're using an old search lib too. I would do: try the search using REST, then try to match to whatever this lib is doing. Print the request if possible and compare both